# Java webservice framework recommendation for a for a sever handling http requests

Tags: java, spring, web-services, http, server

I need to create a server that handles http requests and routes then to the appropriate action. I plan on using Java only because it is what I am most comfortable with.

I have created a web application before using Java, and Jersey. But or this web server, it doesn't need to be Restful. It needs to send RPC-style requests. So the url would have query parameters.

What would be a good java framework to use? I tried Spring but stopped because it seemed very overkill to me. How I understand Spring is that it is a framework used for large scale projects that have many moving parts. Spring makes the connection between those parts easier.

I was thinking of jax-ws but it seems outdated from the resources Ive found.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like OR you are not willing to use Spring/any other framework, then you can simply write one Simple Servlet which handles your requests through different Controller classes (does process business logic).

Keeping ONE Single Servlet for the entire application is nothing but following FrontController pattern, which most of the popular frameworks (Spring/Struts/JSF/etc..) does, which has several advantages.

**Web.xml:**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**MyServlet.java (Acts as Front Controller handling all the application requests):**

```
package com.myapp;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet { 

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {                     

    if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/abc")) {
        new ABC().callabc();
    } else if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/def")) {
        new DEF().calldef();
    }

    //ADD Code here to Send Ack back to the caller

   // Ack Code Ends here
  }
}
```